# Uicollectionview chess style grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have to implement a chess style grid view to show some radial progress bar.!
[image]

I made the grid using some inefficient algorithm to do this, since UiCollectionView don't use rows and columns, and it worked, but when the user scrolled the collection to the limit and the "row" of the collection disappear from the screen and the user release the screen and the UICollectionViewCells reappear they switched its colors.

I know the switching happens by the BOOLs, but i don't know how solve this.

[image]
[image]

This is my algorithm (i have 2 differents UICollectionViewCells, one for each color)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *identifierPair = @"CellPair";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell ;
    UILabel *title;

    //...Creating the circle progress bar....


    if ((indexPath.item % 2) == 0) {
        if (isPair) {
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifierPair forIndexPath:indexPath];
            isPair = NO;
            title = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
        }
        else
        {
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            isPair = YES;
            title = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];

        }

    }
    else {
        if (isUneven) {
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifierPair forIndexPath:indexPath];
            isUneven = NO;
            title = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
        }
        else
        {
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            isUneven = YES;
            title = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
        }
    }


    //...Setting the name to the cell....

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is the count changing? Are you removing them when they reach 100%? Are you updating all of them when a row is added or removed? Don't you just want to just always alternate between light and dark (e.g. even for light and odd for dark)?

Comment: this circles are static (I use it just to show information to the user), they won't be removed or added by the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems more the case of using a single checkered background inside the `UICollectionView`, but since I'm not sure that it is doable you could do something like:

```
+ (BOOL)checkersCellAtIndexIsDark:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger squareIndex = indexPath.item % 4;
    return (squareIndex == 0 || squareIndex == 3);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = ([[self class] checkersCellAtIndexIsDark:indexPath])? [UIColor orangeColor] : [UIColor yellowColor];

    // Set other things

    return cell;
}
```

I don't understand why you use different reuseIdentifiers and titleLabels for different backgrounds since I don't notice from the screens, but you can always edit this code

Comment: I didn't see it until now, make the division for 4 solve it all. Thanks SO much!

Comment: I was using different reuse Identifiers just for desperation!, i deleted one of the prototype cells.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have to use 2 different cells to change the background.
All you need is to set the default color of the background and when the indexPath.item is even, just set the other color for the cell background.
But is important to set the default color first, otherwise you will have the same result.

Comment: if i just change the background when indexPath.item is even i will have a full column on beige and the other column brown... because the collection works like this:

`0   1
2   3
4   5
6   7`.